# VScode,The Python path in your debug configuration is invalid

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

I keep getting this error. Other have faced this issue and have asked this question already and I have tried every single solution that was posted but I still get the error.
Things I have tried to solve this problem:

- Uninstalled and reinstalled python and VScode.
- ctrl+shift+p and added python interpreter to path.
- manually entered path in launch.json. "python": "C:\Users\saura\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"

Not sure what more can I do.
I messed around with conda, julia, anaconda without having much knowledge about it and I have a feeling that might be the issue. I did however uninstalled everything regarding conda, julia, anaconda.
If anyone has any idea what could I do, I would really appreciate it.

[image]

Here's the screenshot of json file. I do not see anything wrong with it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the lower right corner of your interface, where you are prompted to choose a **python interpreter**.

[image]

You should just click there or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette and choose **Python:Select Interpreter**, then choose the appropriate python interpreter.

*I know you have tried many ways for this. But here's the problem, you haven't selected a python interpreter for vscode. If none of the methods work, try reinstalling the [python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python).*

Also, if the `"python"` configuration in your `launch.json` is the same as you showed in your question. then it is wrong, you should use `/` or `\\`. like this:

```json
// Example 1
"python": "C:/Users/saura/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe"

// Example 2
"python": "C:\\Users\\saura\\AppData\\Local\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe"
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I did already do ctrl+shift+p and then selecting the interpreter. Also in json file I do have the correct format. 
"Haven't selected a python interpreter for vscode". What does that exactly meaning? Do you mind clarifying? I have the python extension downloaded in vscode and then python 3.10.5 in my laptop's drive. When choosing an interpreter, I choose the python.exe file.

Comment: As your screen shows, everything you've done has clearly failed. vscode didn't find the python interpreter.
Have you tried adding the python interpreter path on your machine using the [first option](https://imgur.com/a/3uD6hmS)?

Answer (score 0):

Post the content of your `launch.json` file so that people can take a look at it.

You Configuration Should Look Like This:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Base",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "args": [],
            "python": "path-to-python"
        }
    ]
}
```

From menu bar of VS Code (Run), go to *Open Configurations* and paste above content after replacing `path-to-python` with yours.

Make sure you are using edited debug configuration when launching the debug for script.